# How to edit an Array field in "Sonata Admin" with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, code-generation, admin, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

With Symfony2, i use "FOSuserBundle". In my Entity "Group", i have an array column named "roles". this is "ArrayCollection" type. How to edit this field "roles" with Admin Generator like "Sonata Admin" when i want to create or edit "Group".

I try with "sonata_type_collection" type but no success.

Do you have an example or link who explain how to do this ?

PS: "roles" use "DC2Type:array" in Group table with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WARNING EDIT: I'm not using Sonata anymore, [@romain-bruckert comment might be better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050576/set-role-for-users-in-edit-form-of-sonata-admin/30105168#30105168).

---

I think that you need to rely on the [SonataAdmin field types](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/field_types.html) :

> - **array**: display value from an array
> - **boolean**: display a green or red picture dependant on the boolean value, this type accepts an `editable` parameter to edit the
>     value from within the list or the show actions
> - **date**: display a formatted date. Accepts an optional `format` parameter
> - **datetime**: display a formatted date and time. Accepts an optional `format` parameter
> - **text**: display a text
> - **trans**: translate the value with a provided `catalogue` option
> - **string**: display a text
> - **decimal**: display a number
> - **currency**: display a number with a provided `currency` option
> - **percent**: display a percentage
> - **choice**: uses the given value as index for the `choices` array and displays (and optionally translates) the matching value
> - **url**: display a link

So for your ArrayCollection, an array type might be good.

Comment: This answer has been accepted, but the SonataAdmin field types are just for the show and list actions... not for editing. How was editing achieved?

Comment: @caponica: For this, you need to rely on the [Sf Form component Types Reference](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html), as Sonata is extending it.

Comment: Thanks, @LaurentG - I also got some help from Gustek on a different thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817255/using-sonata-admin-to-work-with-doctrine-json-array-fields

Comment: As pointed, this answer is WRONG. And you should user "choice" for roles (see also my answer and research on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050576/set-role-for-users-in-edit-form-of-sonata-admin/30105168#30105168)