# Using Sonata Admin to work with Doctrine json_array fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

Is there any 'built in' way to administer Doctrine `json_array` fields using Sonata Admin?

I can't find any useful documentation (or relevant code) in the Symfony / Sonata docs (or code), but I'm hoping that I missed something!

Ideally I would like to see the serialised key/value pairs with a way to delete any of them and add some new ones, but I guess I'm going to have to write that up myself...

Comment: Did you resolve this issue and how? I am having a similar problem? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56131156/sonataadminbundle-json-array-field-giving-invalid-mode-string-conversion-error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You work with `json_array` just like with any array so You can go with [collection type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) or [sonata type collection](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-collection).
I like that sonata type takes care about add/delete JavaScript for You.

Comment: That's really helpful - thank you for the near-instant reply!

Comment: Did you resolve this issue and how? I am having a similar problem? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56131156/sonataadminbundle-json-array-field-giving-invalid-mode-string-conversion-error

Answer (score 4):

In my entity I work with "**json**" type on column "config"

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="config", type="json", nullable=false)
 */
protected $config;
```

You can use basic DataTransformer to transform your value from JSON to string and display it as text in form

```
$formMapper->add('config', 'text', [
    'required' => false,
])        
$formMapper->get('config')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
    function ($tagsAsArray) {
        //object stdclass json, need to be transform as string for render form
        return json_encode($tagsAsArray);
    },
    function ($tagsAsString) { 
        //string, need to be transform as stdClass for json type for persist in DB
        return json_decode($tagsAsString);
    }
));
```