# SonataAdminBundle json_array field giving INVALID MODE / String conversion error

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

I am using `doctrine/dbal v2.9.2` and `sonata-project/admin-bundle 3.47.0`

I have a simple database table with a `data` field of `jsonb` type.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json",nullable=true,options={"jsonb"=true})
 */
private $data;
```

When I try to edit this field with SonataAdminBundle I get errors.

If I import `use Sonata\Form\Type\CollectionType;` then I get error: `INVALID MODE : sb14b159283_data - type : sonata_type_collection - mapping : json`

If I import `use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\CollectionType;` then I receive error: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion").`

The field holds a single array for now. For example `{"image": ["c87d2cb7a1818811d90492bdc5f20e973ee6c1cd.jpg"]}`

I simply tried to define it as `CollectionType::class`

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('id', 'integer')
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('data', CollectionType::class);
    ;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of Doctrine are you running ?

Comment: I added it to the question. It is `doctrine/dbal v2.9.2`.

Comment: answered on [Using Sonata Admin to work with Doctrine json_array fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817255/using-sonata-admin-to-work-with-doctrine-json-array-fields/56804691#56804691)

Comment: See answer on [Work with Json type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817255/using-sonata-admin-to-work-with-doctrine-json-array-fields/56804691#56804691) You must use DataTransformer